# What is the algorithm displaying the calculated answer naturally

Tags: algorithm

I'm prepare to write a calculator program om my computer.
As I know, some calculators allow the entering of equations as well as the answer in a way which things like fractions and integrals are displayed in the way they would normally be written.

For example.
If I enter `√2`,it will display `√2` rather than `1.41421...`.
If I enter something like `3*sqrt(3)/2+sqrt(2)/3`,the answer will display something like `(9*√3+2√2)/6`.
I want to know what is the algorithm of natural display and how to code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible way to do this is to perform all calculations by keeping `√2` as `√2` all the time. You will also have to introduce the knowledge to the program the `√2^2` has a more user friendly representation, namely `2` that may be used for other calculations. How do **you** perform the calculations(on a piece of paper) in a way that the result looks like that when you are done calculating? You will have to teach the computer to do the same.

If you expected a ready-to-use classical algorithm for this, I will have to disappoint  you - there is none.

Comment: In addition, it may be worth noting that these types of systems are known as CASs if you require further research: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system